# how to retrieve data from google form response on submit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form with one field as `name` and I want to sent a email when user submit the form. So how can I retrieve users names from that text field named `name`

```
function conformationEmail(e)
{
  var htmlBodytemplate = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("confirm").getContent();
  var responseUserEmail = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  //var nameofuser = e.namedValues['name'][0];
  var name = "name";
  
  MailApp.sendEmail ({
    to:responseUserEmail,
    subject:nameofuser,
    htmlBody:htmlBodytemplate
  });
  Logger.log("hello");
}
```

I had used `var nameofuser = e.namedValues['name'];` but it doesn't seem to be working

[image]

Comment: The questions doesn't include enough details and the included image has a lot of "noise".  Apparently your script is bounded to a Google Form, you should mention that, also you should mention how the function is called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract response items from a Google Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253706/how-to-extract-response-items-from-a-google-form)

Comment: Anyway, it's very likely that the script is bounded to a Google Form, in such case the form submit event object doesn't include a `namedValues` property, that is the reason of why this isn't working, instead you should use the response object to grab the response to the corresponding form item.  On the Mogdads's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26253706/1595451) there are two possible approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Your not creating a template with `createHtmlOutputFromFile` and you don't use getContent() from a template you must first evaluate the template to get html output

Code:

```
function onSubmitSend(e) {

  let t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ah2");
  t.data = [e.namedValues['Email Address'][0],e.namedValues['COL1'][1],e.namedValues['COL2'][1]]
  let html = t.evaluate().getContent();
  MailApp.sendEmail({to: e.namedValues['Email Address'][0],subject: "Submission Confirmation",htmlBody: html });
}
```

html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <title> </title>
  </head>
  <body>
   This is to confirm that we have received your form submission.  Your responses were  <?= data[1] ?> and <?= data[2] ?>.
  </body>
</html>
```

image of form:

[image]