# How to get value of form response?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I have an app that sends emails after a form is submitted and I would like to use the form response data from a couple of questions in the email subject.

currently the email subject is pulling from this

const subject = "Text -" + this.title

I was thinking, but am not sure how to reference a specific form question using getResponse() or if this is the proper solution
const subject = "Text -" + this.title + getResponse()

Comment: We don't know what library do you use and how does your code works.

Comment: https://github.com/ashtonfei/google-apps-script-projects/blob/GAS-070/app.js#L179

This is the project I'm trying to edit for my needs, line 179 is what I want to change to include answer from form question, so its in title of email sent, but do not know how

Comment: Are you using the spreadsheet onFormSubmit or the form onFormSubmit? If it's the spreadsheet then look at the event object values or namedValues.  Here's a [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: From form - On form submit is the trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that the source that lead you to `getResponse()` was refering to [FormApp.ItemResponse.getResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getresponse).

In order to be able to used this method, first your code should grab the [FormApp.FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) which is usally got from for form submit event object from a Form trigger, but the project that you are referreing is using a spreadsheet trigger which might make things easier as it already includes two properties with the response values:

- values
- namedValues

For details please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit

Related

- [How to extract response items from a Google Form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26253706/1595451)
- [How to get form values in the submit event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43429161/1595451)